# Laravel 5.6 - Can't Update Enum Value

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a field of type enum in the database that allows me to know if the user has activated his account or not.

Here is the corresponding migration:

```
 /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->enum("activated", [0,1])->default(0);
            $table->enum("role", [0,1,2,3,4])->default(0);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn(['activated', "role"]);
        });
    }
```

Now if I try to update the value of this field, the value is not changed and no error occurs.

```
$user = User::find(2);
$user->activated = 1;
$user->save();
```

I note that in my model user all fields can be filled:

**In App\User**

```
   protected $guarded = [];
```

**Does somebody have an idea ?**

Comment: @DaveCarruthers I tried it does not work

Comment: Why not use a `boolean` type here? `$table->boolean('activated')->default(false);`

Comment: @ceejayoz Oh yes, not bad your idea. But for the case of user's role?

Comment: Roles, IMO, should be handled via an entirely separate set of tables. There should be a `roles` table, and a `user_roles` table (with `user_id` and `role_id` foreign keys), so that users can have multiple roles - a very common requirement.

Comment: @ceejayoz ok thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented by ceejayoz : you should have other table `user_roles` to map many to many relationship among users and roles.

Here why your value is not updating is because.

> If you store a number into an ENUM column, the number 
>    is treated as the index into the possible values, and the 
>    value stored is the enumeration member with that index.
>    (However, this does not work with LOAD DATA, which 
>    treats all input as strings.) If the numeric value is quoted, 
>    it is still interpreted as an index if there is no matching 
>    string in the list of enumeration values. For these 
>    reasons, it is not advisable to define an ENUM column 
>    with enumeration values that look like numbers, because
>    this can easily become confusing. For example, the 
>    following column has enumeration members with string 
>    values of '0', '1', and '2', but numeric index values of 1, 2, and 3:

AS you are storing numeric value it treated it as index not value. To tread this as value you should use quotes `"` to make it values instead of index.

Here

```
$table->enum("activated", [0,1])->default(0);
// it stores value `0` in index `1` and value `1` in index `2`
```

When you do

```
$user->activated = 1;
// `1` which is number treated as index whose value is `0`
// to tread `1` as `1` you need to pass it with quotes `'1'` or `"1"`
```

It means it's overwritting your value from `0` to `0` as  `1` becames `0` at the time of storing.and `2` will be `1`

[Read from docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html)